# SWF only works in bin-debug/-release-directory

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, swfobject

if I run Flash Builder RUN an Actionscript-Project, it works. Also if I go directly into the directory bin-debug and start the html or swf it works fine!
If I build the project, I can also run it from the bin-release directory, but i I copy/move the directory to another place (local or webspace) it does not work!

Can somebody help me to build the project this way, I can upload it?

I am a newb, so plz be kind :-D

Comment: Are you copying the entire contents of the folder right? Including the .js flies and graphic assets that are not embedded? My recommendation is to first try to publish a super basic project, something with 1 label to see if that works.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work": Did you get any errors?